# rails validates with inclusion and one value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this in my Foo class :

```
MIN = 2
MAX = 42

validates :max_users,
            presence: true,
            inclusion: { in: MIN..MAX }
```

I need to allow "0" value AND the MIN..MAX interval, how can I add zero as possible value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an array of values for `in` option as well:

```
validates :max_users,
            presence: true,
            inclusion: { in: (MIN..MAX).to_a + [0] }
```